# Hide a range of data labels in 'pie of pie' in Excel

Tags: excel, pie-chart

I have several graphs linked to a data template - The data in the template changes depending on the selected business unit.

I have approximately 50 categories in the data template linked to a pie chart and depending on the unit selected I could therefore have anything from 0-50 categories shown as a percentage in my pie chart.

What I want to do is only show categories with a value over 2% in my pie.
So, I have used the 'pie of pie' function to make the cut at 2% but *I do not want to see the second pie at all*.
How do I hide all the values and data labels in the pie of pie chart? Ie Can I use formatting in the pie of pie chart to hide values between 0-2%?

I have searched for a solution to this but only come accross answers on how to hide zero values:
Example: Format Data Labels, Number, Format Code: 0%;;; OR 0%;[White][=0]General;General

I need a solution to this that does not involve changing my original data (ie I do not want to group my categories under 2% into an 'other' category in my data template as the categories will change depending on the unit selected)

Any advice?

Comment: If you want to see the sum of the low percentage categories as a pie part, then you have to group them somehow. If they simply shall not visible, then they should not be in the data for the diagram. Either the logic, that links the data dependent of the business unit, should not link them, or they should be hidden after linking. For further suggestions I need informations about the logic, that links the data dependent of the business unit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but was looking for this myself and just figured it out.. First format the second pie so that each slice has no fill (becomes invisible), to speed this up just set the first slice to no fill and then highlight each slice and select F4 to repeat last action. Next select any slice from the main chart and hit CTRL+1 to bring up the Series Option window, here set the gap width to 0% (this will centre the main pie as much as possible) and set the second plot size to 5% (which is the minimum it will allow), and you have made your second pie invisible!